# any way to have mouse stick to a curve in matlab?

Tags: matlab, mouseevent

I have a java program with a Gaussian plotted in the range -3 to 3 (f = exp(-x^2/3)). I capture the mouse event and have the mouse can only move along the curve so to pick up the value (f) and the corresponding x. Is that possible to implement the same thing in matlab? I search for mouse event in matlab but seems it doesn't have any low-level mouse control or even response.

As suggested by A. Donda, I tried datacursormode. If I have two curves shown on the same figure, I can easily trace the position of the mouse on either curve, I wonder if it is possible to capture the event upon the tracing so I can return the value of the other curve at the same x-coordinate while I am tracing the other curve? Or if it possible to change the way or content the yellow tip shown? What I really interesting is the sum or difference or product of the function values from two curve at the same x position.

Comment: To modify the datatip, right click, then "edit text function" will open a callback editor.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the same thing, but you can use "Tools / Data Cursor" in the figure window, also accessible by the "yellow note with crosshairs" icon in the toolbar, or the function `datacursormode`.

Comment: that's looks pretty interesting, it gives me some new idea (I edited my question) but don't know if it is possible to implement it in matlab

Comment: I think Magla's last comment on your question should help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can't easily set the mouse position with matlab (see [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243808) for an example). As mentioned by @A. Donda, the straightforward solution is to use the data cursor.

**Set the "stick-to-curve" behavior with your mouse**

With `datacursormode on`, you can right click on the axes and set `Selection Style` to `Mouse Position`. Then, select a first point on the curve. A data tip containing `(x,y)` will appear. Select a second point but keep the mouse button down: the data cursor will stick to the curve and will follow the mouse.

**Set the "stick-to-curve" behavior programatically**

Get the handle of `datacursormode` and set the `SnapToDataVertex` property to `off` before calling `datacursormode on`

```
cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
set(cursorMode, 'SnapToDataVertex', 'off');
datacursormode on
```